# Use inline javascript to set some values

Tags: javascript

So I have this:

```
<span><script>someFunction("${theValue}");</script></span>
```

I just want this to set the value of the "span" to whatever the result of the call to the `someFunction` is.

How do i do that in an inline - or whatever - manner?

Comment: Give the span an `id`.  Then in the script, get that element, and change its text.  It doesn't matter where the script is.

Comment: @Amy this is actually part of a loop - can i avoid giving the span an id and just get the span that the js code is in somehow?

Comment: I don't think so, no.  You need a way of uniquely identifying the span you want to target.  I suggest expanding the question to include the loop.

Comment: In JS, "inline" (basically anything) is considered a bad practice. Perhaps there's a better answer out there -- if you give us more context maybe we can help you find a better solution?

Comment: @SterlingArcher nah, i'm cutting all that code, i don't want to add infrastructure, it's for a quick demo

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NJ5sK/ whether this works for you